# Full of (piss|pith) and vinegar

Tags: idioms, expressions, slang

Re: the expression:

> "Full of (piss|pith) and vinegar"

Are both correct/acceptable? Is one preferred?

Comment: That sounds like something Bear Grylls would like.

Comment: Says Grandpa Simpson: _"I used to just be full of vinegar."_

Comment: So, is this an eggcorn?

Comment: "Pith and vinegar" is just a euphemism, IMO. (Unless someone misheard someone with a lisp say, "Piss and vinegar.")

Comment: In Australia we say "Full of piss and bad manners".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are *no* appearances of "pith and vinegar" in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/).

Plotting an [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pith%20and%20vinegar,piss%20and%20vinegar&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of "piss and vinegar" against "pith and vinegar" shows a similar result; "pith and vinegar" just isn't there. It doesn't mean that "pith and vinegar" is incorrect; it just means that writers prefer to capture the full flavor of the idiom.

(It appears "piss and vinegar" itself is surprisingly recent origin; [this source](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/145600.html) dates its first appearance in the corpus to 1938, in John Steinbeck's "The Grapes of Wrath.")

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The OED lists the *piss* version only. Also, it's far more common on the web. I've never heard the *pith* version.

Comment: Agreed.  [This source](http://www.171english.cn/html/errors/pith.html) suggests that the "pith" version was just for the sake of politeness, which  I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Also, interested in some thoughts about history/etymology. Should I post as a new question or update to this question?

Comment: It's an [eggcorn](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/), but it's not in the database yet. Be the first to enter it. As for etymology, _piss_ and _vinegar_ are both acidic -- or at least distasteful -- liquids. Since _piss_ is tabu, _pith_ can be used as a euphemism  that has the semantic benefit of referring to a mass substance that one can be full of, as well as the phonetic benefit that makes it an eggcorn -- sounding almost the same as the original word.

Comment: In addition to what John Lawler said, it is conceivable that the expressions "pith and substance" and "pith and marrow" may also have played a minor part in "pith and vinegar" appearing valid.

Answer (score -3):

But how's about us looking at pith(not toxic piss)as the strength and growth naturally such that oversee$ that that which surrounds all that it encapsulates the many avenues by which plants,and ourselves are fed the nutritriants that we need just as the Pith of any stalk, be it flowehr, tree, or bush. It is the substance that is fundamental in...ok, I'm so done...y'all can figure it out yourselves! Gnite

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425313)